# New columns on Subgroup and Range of percentage in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample df like below:

```
df_test<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group1"),
                "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","C"),
                "Total%"=c(35,26,10,9,5,11,13))
```

The original df is quite big and points to remember about this df:

- There are only 2 Groups "Group1" and "Group2"
- There are multiple sub_groups under one group, the above df shows some of the sub groups
- The total % for a group + subgroup will add upto 100%. In the above it is not since it is just a sample. So, for `Group1`all subgroups like `A, B, C` etc. will add upto 100 & so for "**Group2**". Subgroups for both **Group1** and **Group2** will be more or less same

**Ask:**

I need to create a column called `Category` which lets works on range of `Total%` on an `Group.Name` level. The conditions for creating a new column are:

- For every `Group.Name` whereever `Total%` is highest, the category column is whatever the `Sub_group_name` name is.
- For every `Group.Name` and `Total%` between 10-30, the category column is "**New_Group1**".
- For every `Group.Name` and `Total%` less than 10, the category column is "**New_Group2**".

**Expected Output:**

```
df_output<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group1"),
                     "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","C"),
                     "Total%"=c(35,26,10,9,5,11,13),
                     "category"=c("A","A","New_Group1","New_Group1","New_Group2","New_Group1","New_Group1"))
```

Comment: The `Total%` is a `factor` column in your example.  I think it should be `numeric`?

Comment: In the `df_output` one of the value is changed to 12 in 'Total' which is `5` in the 'df_test'

Comment: Also, please check the 'catgory' in your 'df_output'.  Some values should be in 'New_Group1' based on the condition

Comment: Actually "10" is in NewGroup2 because when I said 10-30 I meant both 10 &30 not included. But after seeing the solution, I got it how to cut..so no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `cut` to create the `labels` with the corresponding `breaks` and then replace the 'Total.' that is the highest in each 'Group.Name' with the correspoding 'Sub_group_name'

```
library(dplyr)
df_test %>% 
  group_by(Group.Name) %>%
  mutate(category = as.character(cut(`Total%`, breaks = c(-Inf,10, 30, Inf), 
          labels = c("New_Group2", "New_Group1", "Other"), right = FALSE)), 
         category = case_when(`Total%` == max(`Total%`) ~ 
                          Sub_group_name,
                                   TRUE ~ category))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   Group.Name [2]
#  Group.Name Sub_group_name `Total%` category  
#  <chr>      <chr>             <dbl> <chr>     
#1 Group1     A                    35 A         
#2 Group2     A                    26 A         
#3 Group1     B                    10 New_Group1
#4 Group2     C                     9 New_Group2
#5 Group2     D                     5 New_Group2
#6 Group2     E                    11 New_Group1
#7 Group1     C                    13 New_Group1
```

#### data

```
df_test<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2",
        "Group2","Group1"),
             "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","C"),
          "Total%"=c(35,26,10,9,5,11,13), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
              check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Asked a extended question here, if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533132/new-column-based-on-different-groups-and-different-subgroups/52533776?noredirect=1#comment92008090_52533776