# New column based on different groups and different subgroups

Tags: r, dataframe

This question is extension to the below question so please refer the question for data and other information.

[New columns on Subgroup and Range of percentage in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52521310/new-columns-on-subgroup-and-range-of-percentage-in-another-column?noredirect=1#comment91983037_52521310)

In the above question, the output was same name for the same subgroups i.e. **Group1** with **10-30%** and **Group2** with **10-30%** is having same name i.e. `New_Group1`.

**Updated Ask**:

1. Can the names of groups be different as per my Group_Name. So,**Group1** between 10-30% is called `Group1_1` whereas **Group2** between 10-30% is called `Group2_1`
2. Also, in the above question the cuts are same across two groups, can I have cuts accroding to my need. For example: In **Group1** I can have cuts as "`Highest`", "`10-30%`" and "`less than 10%`" whereas in **Group2**, I can have cuts as "`Highest`","`40-10%`","`10-5%`" and "`less than 5%`".

3.So new categories will be like, for highest it will be the `Sub_Group_name`. For, the number of cuts we have, minus the highest, the new groups would be names as **Group1_1**, **Group1_2** etc.

**Updated Sample Data:**

```
df_test<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group1"),
                "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","C"),
                "Total%"=c(35,16,2,29,4,8,13))
```

**Updated Output Data:**

```
df_Updated_output<- data.frame("Group.Name"=c("Group1","Group2","Group1","Group2","Group2","Group2","Group1"),
                     "Sub_group_name"=c("A","A","B","C","D","E","C"),
                     "Total%"=c(35,16,2,29,4,8,13),
                     "category"=c("A","New_Group2_1","New_Group1_2","C","New_Group2_3","New_Group2_2","New_Group1_1"))
```

The reason for new question is becuase of the updated ask the solution will change drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below mentioned ifelse condition will provide you the required output.

```
df_test$category <- ifelse(df_test$Group.Name == "Group1" & df_test$Total. >=10 & df_test$Total. <= 30,"Group1_1",ifelse(df_test$Group.Name == "Group1" & df_test$Total. < 10,"Group1_2",ifelse(df_test$Group.Name == "Group2" & df_test$Total. >10 & df_test$Total. <= 40,"Group2_1",ifelse(df_test$Group.Name == "Group2" & df_test$Total. >=5 & df_test$Total. <= 10,"Group2_2",ifelse(df_test$Group.Name == "Group2" & df_test$Total. < 5,"Group2_3",df_test$Sub_group_name)))))
```

i think you have provided wrong data in group2_2 (5% to 40%) condition so please have a look at my condition and make the changes accodingly.

Comment: 40-10%","10-5% - instead of this i made a single value as 40% to 5 % it was wrong in your condition.

Comment: I want to separate cuts, I at 40-10 and other at 10-5

Comment: Rahul i have updated the answer . please have  a look